# Perl regexp - replace all digits in a string with # unless they have a certain prefix

Tags: regex, perl, negative-lookbehind

I am trying to replace all numbers in a string with '#', provided that they don't have a specific prefix.
The numbers may appear as part of a word, or as a word on their own.

For example, using ABC as the prefix, this is the desired result.

Input:

```
sdkfjsd 12312981 sdkfjsdfhbnmawd 1298 ,smdfsdnfk2342423 
sdlkfsdfs 20349 ABC1203912 2034234aac <-- ABC<number> stays, the other numbers do not
ABC1203912
```

Result (note that lines 2,3 have ABC with a number):

```
sdkfjsd # sdkfjsdfhbnmawd # ,smdfsdnfk#
sdlkfsdfs # ABC1203912 #aac <-- ABC<number> stays, the other numbers do not
ABC1203912
```

I tried to do it with a negative-look behind regexp: `s/(?<!ABC)\d+/#/g`. 
In this case only the first digit after ABC will not be replaced, the rest will.

My next step would be to split the string into parts that contain `ABC\d+` , and perform a simple replace on the other parts.

Will appreciate any advice how to do the whole thing without splitting into multiple strings.

Thanks!

Edit 1: moved aac back to proper position.
Edit 2: I am using perl 5.8.5, in case this is relevant. I can't update to a newer version due to compatibility issues with code that I don't control.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "My next step would be to split the string into parts that contain `ABC\d+`, and perform a simple replace on the other parts.", but you can do the replace [like so](http://regex101.com/r/pA0lR9).

Comment: Your result does not match your input, you moved the `aac` field up.

Comment: @Jerry - If I can't find a way to use negative look behind or anything else I will resort to splitting the string and working on the substrings, which will be simpler to parse. Also appreciate the example, but in Perl negative look behind must be of fixed width, so that would not run.

Comment: @Oron Ah, I get it now. Yea, TLP mentioned it a little earlier. PCRE standing for Perl Compatible RegEx, I thought that it would work. It's not a big deal though, I put the workaround in my answer.

Comment: @Oron It might be a simpler and more maintainable solution to split the string and reassemble it. You can use a non-destructive split, such as `my @fields = split /(\s+)/, $line` loop and skip lines that match `/^ABC\d+$/`, and then join it back together with `join "", @fields`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand what you mean by "My next step would be to split the string into parts that contain `ABC\d+`, and perform a simple replace on the other parts.", but it looks like it is not your main issue here. Do let me know otherwise.

To match every digit that is not preceded by the keyword `ABC`, then you can use this regex:

```
(?<!ABC|\d)\d+
```

This prevents the matching of a digit if there is `ABC` before it, or another digit (thus preventing `\d+` to match if starting from the middle of a digit.

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/pA0lR9)

Note that you had two parts of your string in your question moved around. I'm taking only the input that you used.

---

If the above doesn't work (e.g. the regex engine says the pattern in the lookbehind cannot be of variable width, or something along these lines), then the alternate equivalent is:

```
(?<!ABC)(?<!\d)\d+
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/iC3eN3)

Comment: `Variable length lookbehind not implemented in regex m/(?<!ABC|\d)\d+/`

Comment: @TLP Huh, I thought that perl could. That's easily fixable though.

Comment: It works for the test cases, but it also matches partially, which might be an issue. E.g. `RABC123` is kept.

Comment: @TLP That's true. I didn't put a word boundary because I don't know whether the OP wants to substitute or not in such cases. I am assuming that digits preceded by `ABC` should be substituted in any circumstance. Otherwise, it would be with a word boundary: `(?<!\bABC)(?<!\d)\d+`

Comment: Digits directly after ABC should not be replaced (ABC123 ==> ABC123). Any other digits should be (even 123ABC ==> #ABC).

Comment: @Oron Are they not remaining the same after the replace for the former? And it looks to me that the latter is being correctly replaced.

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what it is you want, not least because the `2034234aac` field has been modified strangely in your example.

But this modification of your own negative look-behind may be useful. Note that it leaves intact *any* sequence starting with `ABC`, such as `ABCX1234`. It's not clear whether that is correct behaviour.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $s = <<'__END_TEXT__';
sdkfjsd 12312981 sdkfjsdfhbnmawd 1298 ,smdfsdnfk2342423 
sdlkfsdfs 20349 ABC1203912 2034234aac <-- ABC<number> stays, the other numbers do not
ABC1203912
__END_TEXT__

$s =~ s/\b(?!ABC)[a-z]*\K\d+/#/gi;

print $s;
```

or, for versions of Perl 5 earlier than 10, use this

```
$s =~ s/\b((?!ABC)[a-z]*)\d+/$1#/gi;
```

**output**

```
sdkfjsd # sdkfjsdfhbnmawd # ,smdfsdnfk# 
sdlkfsdfs # ABC1203912 #aac <-- ABC<number> stays, the other numbers do not
ABC#
```

Comment: Running this through Perl -wc says "Unrecognized escape \K passed through at ...". This also doesn't replace any digits in my actual input (sorry, can't share that unfortunately). If it matters, I am using perl 5.8.5 for this particular case and can't update much higher.

Also - fixed the example so aac is now back in it's proper place.

Comment: @Oron: Okay thanks. Lack of support for `\K` means you are running on a *very* old version of Perl. It has been valid since version 10 of Perl 5 five years ago. I've added a version for earlier Perls.

Comment: Better, but still no cigar. ww28b for example did not change to ww#b. I marked Jerry's answer above as correct , it also worked for my real life input. Appreciate the effort though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a "zero-width negative lookbehind assertion": only match if not immediately preceded by something.

Eg. to match a digit not preceeded by `ABC`:

```
(?<!ABC)\d
```

You have already got this far, but the next step to match prefix and multiple digits:

```
(?<!ABC)\d+
```

doesn't directly help, because you need to not match.

So rephrase the question slightly:

> Replace a digit not following the prefix and one or more digits

Ie. in "ABC123" you don't want to replace the 1, 2 or 3. And we can extend the zero-width negative lookbehind assertion to include digits:

```
(?<!ABC\d+)\d
```

and thus exclude the digits following the prefix as well.

***NB*** this assumes Perl support for variable width lookbehinds: certainly the first extensions of regexes to include lookbehinds they had to be fixed width, but it has been a while since I used Perl regexes seriously so I am assuming the Perl regex implementation has been extended to match other platforms.

EDIT: Oops, s/positive/negative/ lookbehind.

Comment: It has not been so extended.

Comment: Negative lookbehind is `(?<!...)`.

Comment: @TLP interesting: Perl always used to set the standard for regexes.

Comment: @Richard There is an alternative, the escape `\K` (keep) which will do something similar. I.e. `(?<=foo)` would be `foo\K`. But negating it would be trickier.